# Requesting input on this MVC Widget approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I realize this question is a bit subjective but it seems like best practices are still evolving for ASP.Net MVC.

I went searching for examples on how to implement sub/partial views with their own controllers so that I could produce self contained widgets and I came across this article.

http://blog.codeville.net/2008/10/14/partial-requests-in-aspnet-mvc/

It works but I'm curious if anyone with a bit more experience with this kind of thing can see some roadblocks I may run into with this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally your primary views model should contain the model data needed to relay to the partial..  If need be, use a composite model, or pass the extra data in via the ViewData.